# Is it possible to verify grub installation without rebooting?

Tags: grub2

I've been bitten by this so many times, and today after the `openssl` updates in my server grub complained that I should install it again since the "hard disks that it was previously installed do not exist".

I have a raid 1 installation with the following setup (according to bootinfoscript):

```
> ============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================
> 
>  => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at
> sector 1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
>     for (mduuid/d2a04f98760e2b3cc23ba87845667605)/grub on this drive.  
>
> => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of
>     the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
>     for (mduuid/d2a04f98760e2b3cc23ba87845667605)/grub on this drive.

My mount points are:

> /dev/md2 on / type ext4 (rw) 

> /dev/md1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)

And mduuid seems to match the ones bootinfoscript mentions:

> ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-*
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 19 11:37 /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-38048286:e3004e47:510ca3e1:2bae3f2e -> ../../md2 
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 19 11:37 /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-d2a04f98:760e2b3c:c23ba878:45667605 -> ../../md1 
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 19 11:37 /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-e099b695:0143bb58:e4ef7645:0f22ce0b -> ../../md0
```

Running grub-install works, but I want to make sure that after rebooting grub will actually correctly boot up my partitions.

How can I verify it?

Comment: I do not use nor really know RAID, but you install grub to the root of the RAID not to the MBR of a drive. If you run Boot-Repair you then might get a message like this. No boot loader is installed in the MBR of 
    /dev/mapper/isw_cdjacjeebj_VOLUME_0.
Where the mapper is your RAID volume.

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/61400/how-do-i-tell-if-grub-is-installed-on-a-device

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think you can just check whether this will works or not before trying to do it, but instead you can get a preview of your GRUB instantly so you can be sure that your new configuration is loaded correctly in GRUB.

This could be achieved using a tool called `grub-emu`.

`man grub-emu`

```
NAME
       grub-emu - GRUB emulator

SYNOPSIS
       grub-emu [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       GRUB emulator.

       -r, --root-device=DEV
              use DEV as the root device [default=guessed]

       -m, --device-map=FILE
              use FILE as the device map [default=/boot/grub/device.map]

       -d, --directory=DIR
              use GRUB files in the directory DIR [default=/boot/grub]

       -v, --verbose
              print verbose messages
```

Easily install `grub-emu` using command line:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-emu
```

To run it just use terminal to run this command:

```
grub-emu
```

Comment: Is this a reliable test for grub2 installations? Also, keyboard input doesn't seem to work for the menu that appears; is there a trick for enabling it?

Comment: I cant close `grub-emu`, only way to stop it is `pkill -SIGKILL -fe grub-emu`, keyboard input not working either

Comment: @MichaelScheper this fixes the interactiveness https://serverfault.com/a/847429/163750 :). Basically, `xterm -e grub-emu` and keep the focus on xterm not the grub-emu window!

Comment: @AquariusPower press c in boot menu, then type exit

Comment: @Tschallacka for me that also does not work, emulator does not react on any inputs at all.

Comment: You have to set focus to the termial in which you started the emulator to be able to do inputs! The window of the emulator self will not react to any inputs at all.

Comment: to close grub-emu  type `c` and then `halt`

Comment: in my case it shows menu entries, but after selecting boot entry it says "error: sparse file not allowed", "can't find command linux", "can't find command initrd". but my os has booted successfully, so it looks like false negative.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/61400/how-do-i-tell-if-grub-is-installed-on-a-device) uses `file -s /dev/sda` to see if the GRUB MBR has been successfully installed.  Past that, you could definitely double-check the values in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to make sure the UUIDs match up with the values in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, and make sure that everything looks right in `/boot/grub/device.map`.  If that file is wrong you'll have trouble with (hdX) specifications in grub.cfg.

Managing these files manually isn't necessary though if you're using `update-grub` after installing grub on replacement drives.  The biggest gotchas in my experience have been not updating the GRUB configuration, not installing GRUB on all the drives, or improper partitioning that makes it so you can't install GRUB without using --force.

Comment: That answer only uses `file -s` for grub1, for grub 2 there is a second answer suggesting `dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings|grep GRUB`

Comment: there is no "/boot/grub/device.map", but thx for that link !